# How to prevent GCE enforcer from deleting SSH/HTTP/HTTPS firewall rules?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've had instances on GCE hosting multiple websites for years. Suddenly, without any warning or notice, my instances went unreachable on 6/19.

After wasting several hours trying to debug this, I found that a `gceenforcer@system.gserviceaccount.com` service account was deleting firewall rules from my account! Even if I click "Enable HTTP/HTTPS traffic" when configuring the instance, a few minutes later the GCE enforcer deletes the rules again.

I've tried re-adding the rules back via the gcloud CLI. Tried creating a new VPC network. Tried creating new instances in different zones. Each time GCE enforcer kicks in after a few minutes and deletes the rules.

So many questions (and so frustrating!). What is GCE enforcer? Why is it deleting my firewall rules without permission or notice? How do I disable it?

Comment: GCE Enforcer enforces rules for Google owned projects. This is also part of Forseti. If your project is a Google project you cannot change things. If you have setup Forseti, contact that admin for Forseti or investigate its configuration. You have not provided enough details to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley! Happy to provide more info, what would be helpful? How do I confirm if my project is Google owned? It's a really old project that I own AFAICT and as I mentioned earlier, the problem suddenly started 6/19 but nothing has changed at my end. I don't have Forseti setup either. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I would contact Google Support. You either have Forseti installed, a service such as Cloud Functions using the identity of gceenforcer or a Google owned account. To figure this out, you need access to the Google Console or the CLI.